# Are "主题" and "内涵 interchangeable?"

Tags: difference

The sentence I'd like to say is:

> "Yes, it does involve the idea that the face of death brings out the best and the worst in people, yet other themes are involved."

This translates to:

> “对，它蕴含着死亡会揭示人们的最好和最坏的方面的含义，但是本故事也有别的内涵。”

Can you use "主题" instead of "内涵"?

Comment: answer in dictionaries e。g。iciba  主题 theme ； subject  内涵 connotation ； meaning， it is like asking are subject and meaning interchangeable

Comment: Might be an idea to start with good English, then translate. ‘the face of death brings out the best and the worst in people‘  is not good, wherever you got it. You probably mean something like 'facing imminent death can bring out the best and the worst in people' '即将来临死亡带来人们最好及最差的行为' My translation is probably not good, no one here to ask right now.  Then, without more context, I would reject 'yet other themes are involved'. If you start from an illogical premise, how will you arrive a sensible translation. What language are you using?

Answer (score 4):

No.

主题 = 'main topic'

内涵 = 'meaning/connotation'

In English, the *topic* of a conversation is often very different from the *meaning* of the same conversation. The same applies to Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

主题 is a more direct thing, however, 内涵 is more implicit.
For example, if a person make a speech, he may try his best to make the audience clear with his 主题 of the speech but for one sentence of his speech, there might be some 内涵 hidden in it which the audience may not understand if they only focus on the literal meaning of the sentence.